# HTML5 in Safari 9.0.1 (11601.2.7.2) - `html5test.com

Tags: safari, html

According to html5test.com, Safari now supports HTML5. I am specifically interested in the HTML5 tag parameter `required`.

However, when I add the `required` parameter to my form, Safari ignores it. I have tested the page with FireFox and it works.

So, does Safari support HTML5 or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari does support HTML5 and does support form validation, however support for 'required' in Safari on OS X and iOS is 'partial'.

> Partial support refers to lack of notice when form with required fields is attempted to be submitted.

<sup>Source: [caniuse.com/#search=required](http://caniuse.com/#search=required)</sup>

Implementation is off-topic here, but feel free to search for solutions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not support this attribute, you need to use JavaScript. This page contains a hacky solution, that should add the desired functionality:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/#toc-safari